# How to slideToggle on click only children of clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have 2 divs with 2 divs inside it like this

```
<div id="div1" class="div">
    <div class="flip">Click to slide down panel</div>
    <div class="panel">Hello world!</div>
</div>

<div id="div2" class="div">
    <div class="flip">Click to slide down panel</div>
    <div class="panel">Hello world!</div>
</div>
```

And my JavaScript is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flip").click(function(){
         $( ".panel" ).children( ".panel" ).slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

The example is in https://jsfiddle.net/msjaasfk/2/

So i want when one `.flip` is clicked to show only the `.panel` in the same div not all divs with `.panel` class.

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting and toggling *all* of the `.panel` elements. Modify your code so that only the `.panel` element corresponding to the clicked element is toggled:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/v24857r7/)

```
$(".flip").click(function() {
  $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
});
```

- `this` is a reference to the clicked `.flip` element
- The [`.next()` method](https://api.jquery.com/next/) will select the next sibling element (in this case `.panel`).

As a side note, you can also modify your code so that only one single panel is open at a time:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/b0p0kdrv/)

```js
$(".flip").click(function() {
  $('.panel').not($(this).next()).slideUp();
  $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```css
.panel,
.flip {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e5eecc;
  border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
.panel {
  padding: 50px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" class="div">
  <div class="flip">Click to slide down panel</div>
  <div class="panel">Hello world!</div>
</div>

<div id="div2" class="div">
  <div class="flip">Click to slide down panel</div>
  <div class="panel">Hello world!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your context, `.panel` is going to select all of the elements with the `panel` class. In the click event for the `.flip` element, you could use jQuery's [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to select only the next `.panel` You may want to specify the `.panel` selector, in case your HTML structure inside the div changes

```
$(this).next(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
```

Here's the full example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".flip").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
.panel,
.flip {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e5eecc;
  border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
.panel {
  padding: 50px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" class="div">
  <div class="flip">Click to slide down panel</div>
  <div class="panel">Hello world!</div>
</div>

<div id="div2" class="div">
  <div class="flip">Click to slide down panel</div>
  <div class="panel">Hello world!</div>
</div>
```